# Epoll vs Libevent for Bittorrent like application

Tags: c, multithreading, bittorrent, epoll, libevent

I am implementing bit torrent for P2p file sharing. Let's say, Maximum of among 100 peers sharing simultaneously. TCP Connections are setup between each peer to every other peer. Initially, One peer has whole file and it starts sharing pieces and subsequently, all peers share their pieces.

Typically, piece size is 50kB - 1MB. I am wondering, What is the best approach to write such application in C. Using threads with epoll or libevent??

Can anybody please give positives/negatives of different possible approaches??

Answer (score 1):

If we're only talking about 100 peer connections at any given moment, the traditional approach of using [select](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) or [poll](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll) on a group of TCP sockets will work out just fine.

EPoll helps solve the problem of when you need to scale to thousands of long running connections.   Read the doc on the [C10K problem](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html) for more details.

I've heard good things about libevent. I believe it's an abstraction on top of epoll and other socket functions that provides a few nice things. If it makes your programming easier, then by all means use it. But you probably don't need it for performance.

Answer (score 0):

`Libevent` is essentially a wrapper around `epoll`, mostly considered for writing good portable code. Since its a wrapper, drawbacks of `epoll` will be retained and does not add much from performance perspective. If portability is not concern, `epoll` should just work fine. Even better, if the volume is considerably less than one still use `poll`.